# String Builder Append function cutting off first character

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, append, stringbuilder

i'm using stringbuilder in a project here with nested loops and my append statement seems to cut the first character value off of only one of my column values.  Here is the loops

```
For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In gridData.Rows
            I = X.CreateElement("I")
            B.AppendChild(I)

            Dim sb As New StringBuilder

            sb.Append("|P|")
            For Each dc As DataColumn In dr.Table.Columns


                ''for ticker value, since it's a link, we need to add a character to the beginning of the value otherwise, the 1st character in
                ''in the ticker gets truncated. This was recommended by the folks at Treegrid. Only for "link" type columns. 
                ''Same goes for hhname. PD 11.11.2010
                ''Need to replace null values with space as it creates an issue on the UI with cerain browser versions in that the cell borders disappear.
                ''By placing in a blank space, it resolves any issues. Another recommendation by treegrid.
                If dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHTICKER" OrElse dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHHHNAME" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "ACNTNUM" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "STATEMENTGROUP" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHSSNUMBER" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHLINKLABEL" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "CACCOUNTNUM" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHSECURITY_SYMBOL" Then
                    If dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "CACCOUNTNUM" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHSECURITY_SYMBOL" Then
                        sb.Append(IIf(IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), "~&nbsp;", dr.Item(dc.ColumnName).ToString).ToString & "|")
                    Else
                        sb.Append(IIf(IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), "~&nbsp;", "~" & dr.Item(dc.ColumnName).ToString).ToString & "|")
                    End If

                ElseIf dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "GROUP1" Then
                    If ((dr.Item("IHHID").ToString.Length > 0) And (dr.Item("IHHID").ToString <> "0")) Then
                        sb.Append(IIf(IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), "~&nbsp;", "~" & dr.Item(dc.ColumnName).ToString).ToString & "|")
                    Else
                        sb.Append(NullConvert.ToString(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)) & "|")
                    End If
                Else

                    'sb.Append(IIf(IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), "~&nbsp;", dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)).ToString & "|")
                    sb.Append(NullConvert.ToString(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)) & "|")
                End If

            Next dc

            Dim XMLString As String = sb.ToString.Substring(0, sb.ToString.Length - 1)
            Dim descText As XmlText = X.CreateTextNode(sb.ToString)

            I.AppendChild(descText)

            icount += 1

            If icount > Constants.MAX_RECORDS Then
                Exit For
            End If

        Next dr
```

The issue i'm having is located here;

```
If dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "CACCOUNTNUM" Or dc.ColumnName.ToUpper = "VCHSECURITY_SYMBOL" Then
                        sb.Append(IIf(IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), "~&nbsp;", dr.Item(dc.ColumnName).ToString).ToString & "|")
                    Else
                        sb.Append(IIf(IsDBNull(dr.Item(dc.ColumnName)), "~&nbsp;", "~" & dr.Item(dc.ColumnName).ToString).ToString & "|")
                    End If
```

Instead of the value for dr.Item being saved as it should something like this "HSC01234" it saves as "SC01234 " with the ending space and the lead character being removed.  The values are never NULL in this instance so the "~nbsp;" will not be hit.  Any help is appreciated.
Thank you,
NickG

Comment: A suggestion. Do the ToUpper on that column name just one time before the if.....

Comment: It looks like the only culprits could be your NullConvert.ToString() function (in your Else condition) or X.CreateTextNode. Could you post the code for those two functions?

Comment: when I changed the inner if...then to just dc.columnname = "cAccountNum" and "vchSecurity_Symbol" the same issue persists.  Even when I set breakpoints throughout the code and check the values they contain the entire value wanted, but when displayed with Response.Write(X.InnerXml) they are missing the lead character, and then innerXml value contains the correct characters.

Comment: @tgolisch unfortunately the nullconvert.tostring() function isn't being touched in this instance and the CreateTextNode is a pre-built function from a third party vendor named TreeGrid that we aren't in control of

Comment: If your first column's name is "HSC01234", then it won't go through the "if" or "else if" condition.  It will go into the "else" condition, which says "sb.Append(NullConvert.ToString(..."

Comment: that was an example of what one of the values contained in the cAccountNum column would be, the value should be something like HSC01234, but it gets truncated into "SC01234 " with an ending blank space.

Answer (score 0):

I found out there was another function playing on the values through javascript that was truncating and fixed it, thank you guys for your help sorry for the open-ended question